# Why is :not not working?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a style to all text, except one under 
.grid. Why is it applied anyway? PS. I can't rely on .grid being a direct child of the parent. In the actual site it's dynamic, and has to be more general.

https://jsfiddle.net/rvLyd156/1/

```css
.amn_main_panel :not(.grid) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="amn_main_panel">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>


  <div class="grid">
    <div>hi</div>
    <div>hi</div>
    <div>hi</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you need to remove the space between the class name and :not

Comment: Your grid is a child of `.amn_main_panel` the divs will all inherit the red colour by your current definition. Removing the space will not do anything @Gerard

Comment: Yea, removing the space means dealing with .amn_main_panel.grid, but that is not what I have.

Comment: Is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cznc4wao/?

Comment: use `.amn_main_panel > div:not(.grid)` if you must use not

Comment: @Huangism , I don't have control over html, so I am trying to figure out how NOT to apply a style to the grid.

Comment: @janehouse my and j08691 comment has your solution

Comment: Can you change the rule to `.amn_main_panel :not(.grid div) { color: red; }`  Not sure if that helps with your actual problem or just this example?

Comment: @Huangism, that would work, but in my actual site, it's a parent of parent of parent... in other words, it's not as simple in and I can't rely on it being x>y>x... I have to be more general...

Comment: @janehouse maybe think simpler, instead of using not, just do another rule that overrides the colour in grid. Hard to come up with a selector when we do not have the full structure but overriding would do the trick

Answer (score 4):

`:not(.grid)` means "Any element that is not a member of the grid class"

It doesn't mean "Any element that is not descended from a member of the grid class".

```
<div class="grid"> <!-- This element does not get the color -->
  <div>hi</div>    <!-- This element does get the color. It is :not(.grid) -->
```

You could replace your descendant combinator with a child combinator:

```
.amn_main_panel > :not(.grid) {
```

Then:

```
<div class="grid"> <!-- This element does not get the color because of the :not -->
  <div>hi</div>    <!-- This element does not get the color because it isn't a child of amn_main_panel -->
```

… but that would depend on your markup being fairly precisely what you have in your example.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.amn_main_panel > div:not([class="grid"]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="amn_main_panel">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>


  <div class="grid">
    <div>hi</div>
    <div>hi</div>
    <div>hi</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.amn_main_panel > div:not(.grid) {
  color: red;
}
```

Does exactly what you want. I would suggest you take a second look at your HTML anyways, since that's the reason you end up using such a complex selector.

```
>
```

This indicates the next selector needs to be an immediate descendant (child).

Comment: Children are always immediate. There are no other kinds.

Comment: Wrong, children are always children. This selector applies only to IMMEDIATE children, that means they are not nested more than once relative to their parent.

Comment: You seem to be confusing children with all kinds of descendants. While I am my grandmonther's grandchild, nobody would ever refer to me as her child. The same terminology is used in CSS. The specification mentions [descendants](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) and [children](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) but never uses the phrase "immediate child"

Comment: Oh, yeah, got what you were saying then.

Answer (score 0):

the child div elements under the .grid get selected by not:(.grid) and are drawn red.

to achieve your objective you could give the selector some context like so

```
.amn_main_panel > :not(.grid)  {
  color: red;
}
```

here we stipulate only children of .amn_main_panel that are :not(.grid) get the red styling.

https://jsfiddle.net/34mpxabs/